# Can't get relative URL's working in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

After three days of vainly looking  everywhere (learning books OpenLayers3, Javascript and Internet) for a solution I put my question here.

The problem is that I can't get relative url's working in OpenLayers3. Here I give an example:

I have a OpenLayersscript in a map/directory called sandbox. 
The relative url's in the HTML part of this script are working, including the relative url in javascript to ol.js.

The problem is that the relative url in the Javascript part of the script don't work. Only when the targetfile (nutsv9_lea.geojson) is in a map/directory underlying the map/directory containing the OpenLayersscript itself, it works, but only in Firefox and not in Google Chrome and  InternetExplorer.

The map sandbox (containing this OpenLayersfile) is located in the maps/directories structure:  C:/ol3_samples/sandbox
The targetfile (nutsv9_lea.geojson) is located in the maps/directories structure:  C:/ol3_samples/assets/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson

The relative url I use is: url: '../assets/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson'

The only working solution (as mentioned above only in Firefox) is the relative url targeting to a underlying map/directory called 'data' containing the target file: url: 'data/nutsv9_lea.geojson' in the map/directory structure: C:/ol3_samples/sandbox/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson

What am I doing wrong or am I overlooking?

```
<script>

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',

    //not working relative url:
    //  url: '../assets/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson'

    //working url (with the targetfile in a directory below the directory containing this script) but only working in Firefox and not working in Chrome and InternetExplorer
    url: 'data/nutsv9_lea.geojson'
  });

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

  var center = ol.proj.transform([5.231819, 52.091852], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

  var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 5
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [vectorLayer],
    view: view
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using file:// or are your files hosted on http:// ?

Comment: Just on my pc in the directorymapstructure:  C:/ol3_samples/sandbox

Comment: Maybe this explains then: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1729

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately I did not succeed to get a working solution from the link provided. 
Maybe because I'm still very new with Javascript and OpenLayers3. New suggestions are very welcome !

Comment: The idea was if you can try to access your page via some webserver, not directly from file system, because the link actually says ol3 does not support local files.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
If OpenLayers 3 can't support local files then we indeed have to use Web services.

Comment: I cant make it into definite answer because I used to work with ol2 where there was a config file, for example, for graphics dir base URL. Things changed with ol3. With web server making proper absolute URL would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of the book where this extract comes from. You need to run a local server (where files are served via http:// and not file://).

You just need to look at p 117.

It tells you can run (as long as you have Python)

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

or in case you got the samples from Packt website, run (if you have node)

`node index.js`

For both NodeJS and Python, you have install instructions (pages 417 & 418),

For Python and people who do not own the book, go to http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/installation/

Comment: As  @thomas suggested you have to use http server, there is another node.js based very simple http-server https://github.com/indexzero/http-server